# How do I store an object and array inside one object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, methods

How do I store an object and array inside one object?
Updating object and array inside one object

const obj = {
key1: 1,
key2: 2,
key3: 3,
keys: ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
};
I got this question in an interview. Now I want to add some new data inside an object. 2hatever you add in object, the "key_"(with added key number) should also be updated in the array which is inside in this main object.

Output should look like this (you can use any methods/functions/loops to update it...its your choice):

const obj = {
key1: 1,
key2: 2,
key3: 3,
key4: 4,
key5: 5,
key6: 6,
.
.
.
.
keys: ['key1', 'key2', 'key3','key4','key5','key6',...]
};

special thanks to E_net4 for helping me to modify this question

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It's not that people doesn't understand your question, it is because this question is not really suitable for Stackoverflow. Why? Because Stack Overflow is not really a tutorial provider or a free code writing service. SO expects askers to put some efforts to try this first and share their code attempts, create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what problems you are facing while attempting to do this. Also check the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking. Goodluck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this? I am not sure what `key_` is in your question.

```js
const obj = { key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: 3, keys: ["key1", "key2", "key3"] };

function addKey(obj, data) {
  const num = obj.keys.length + 1;

  obj[`key${num}`] = data;
  obj.keys.push(`key${num}`);
}

addKey(obj, "hello");
console.log(obj);
```